# Why isn't the bot joining on time?

Tags: python, discord.py

This is my code in python which is for a discord bot. I can't understand why it isn't joining on time. Is the if broken or what.

Any help is appreciated!

```
async def start(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice:
        await ctx.send('Timer has started')
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        while True:
            time = datetime.datetime.now()
            print(str(time.minute) + " " + str(time.second))
            if time.minute == 26:
                voice = await channel.connect()
                source = FFmpegPCMAudio('sound.mp3')
                player = voice.play(source)
                tmt.sleep(72)
                await voice.disconnect()
                print('left the channel')
    else:
        print("Can't join")
        return
```

Comment: do you have the `@bot.command()` decorator above your code?

Comment: @Zichzheng yes, sorry I didn't add it to the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It didn't connect because it was happening too fast.
I just added `time.sleep(1)` before the actions and after the if statement. And it's now joining. Thank you for any help.

Edit: I need to use `asyncio.sleep(1)` instead of `time.sleep(1)`. Because `time.sleep` is buggy and will halt everything. Thank you @damaredayo

Comment: You really do not want to use time.sleep in asynchronous code as it will halt *everything* on the bot, use asyncio.sleep instead.